# How To Test @Controller with Spring Boot 2 and WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am currently trying to test a simple post method in a normal Controller which returns a Mono to redirect to a different page or in this case the home page. I have tried all sorts of different aproaches mocking components but I always seem to be returning a null Mono in the test all works normally via form submission.

```
@Controller
public class AddNewEntryController {

private final EntryService service;

@PostMapping("/add-new-entry")
public Mono<String> addNewEntrySubmit(@ModelAttribute("timeEntry") Entry entry) {
    return service.addTimeKeepingEntry(Flux.just(entry)).then(Mono.just("redirect:/"));
   }
}
```

And the Service Class Code

```
public Mono<Void> addTimeKeepingEntry(Flux<Entry> entry) {
    return entry.flatMap(entry -> Mono.when(repository.save(entry).log("Save to DB"))
            .log("add entry when")).then().log("done");
}
```

And Test Code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = AddNewEntryController.class)
@Import({ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AddNewEntryControllerTest {

@Autowired
WebTestClient webTestClient;

@MockBean
EntryService service;

@Test
public void addNewEntrySubmit() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("month", month);
    formData.add("dateOfMonth", Integer.toString(21));
    formData.add("startTime", "09:00");

    when(service.addEntry(Flux.just(entry1))).thenReturn(Mono.empty());

    webTestClient.post().uri("/add-new-entry").body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData)).exchange().expectStatus().isSeeOther().expectHeader().valueEquals(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "/");
```

Whenever I run the test I am always getting a Null Pointer and after debugging it is pointing to Mono as being Null. Problem is I am not sure which Mono or at which step.

The StackTrace I get is as follows.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.dbeer.timekeeping.UI.AddNewEntryController.addNewEntrySubmit(AddNewEntryController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:243) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1083) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes, see edit above test class is annotated with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = AddNewEntryController.class)
@Import({ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: You might need to show your full code, e.g your controller has 'EntryService' but test has 'TimeKeepingEntryService' with different signatures. I ran your code and it worked fine on a controller level, so I suspect it's a Thyme leaf configuration, which you have not shown.

Comment: @KevinHussey That was a typo. You can see the project at https://gitlab.com/dmbeer/timekeeping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at your project, the issue seems to be the consistency of naming of controllers and the html page.
e.g. in header.html you had a url to link `add-entry` but your controller had `add-new-entry` if you change the url in header to `add-new-entry` it works.

As a clean up, you should use thmyeleaf to generate the URL not a normal href, as if you ever add security later, thymeleaf will add the session id to the URL etc

***********Edit pulled the branch and could reproduce *******

The line

```
 given(service.addTimeKeepingEntry(Flux.just(new TimeKeepingEntry(month, 21, "Tuesday", "09:00", "30", "17:00", "7.5", false)))).willReturn(Mono.empty());
```

is the issue, since Mockito matches on Object.equals here and you have not defined what equals means to your object.

another way is to capture the object passed into the mock
e.g.

```
 @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Flux<TimeKeepingEntry>> captor;

    @Test
    public void addNewEntrySubmit() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        formData.add("month", month);
        formData.add("dateOfMonth", Integer.toString(21));
        formData.add("day", "Tuesday");
        formData.add("startTime", "09:00");
        formData.add("endTime", "17:00");
        formData.add("breakLength", "30");

        given(service.addTimeKeepingEntry(any())).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        webTestClient.post().uri("/add-new-entry")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData)).exchange().expectStatus().isSeeOther().expectHeader().valueEquals(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "/");

        verify(service).addTimeKeepingEntry(captor.capture());
        TimeKeepingEntry timeKeepingEntry = captor.getValue().blockFirst();
        assertThat(timeKeepingEntry.getMonth()).isEqualTo(month);
        //and whatever else you want to test
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this having changed that value I still get a null pointer. java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.dbeer.timekeeping.UI.AddNewEntryController.addNewEntrySubmit(AddNewEntryController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Put some logging in - either your service is returning null or your object is null. Is your dB running correctly- everything worked on mine

Comment: Hi I have just updated the repository against the branch AddNewEntryControllerTest, the mock object seems to be being ignored and the  only null I get is in the service class for the repository. It shouldn't need this due to the mock statement. I really appreciate the help here.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I knew it was something to do with the mockito, becasue of the form data I had to make it match somehow. Jut a really odd error.